# conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type in stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting error when I pass date date for start date and end date that is string value from textbox to sql.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[sp_insert_ProjectDetail]    
(@projectname varchar(max),    
@projectnos varchar(20),    
@Task_assigned varchar(max),  
@Startdate varchar(30),    
@enddate varchar(30),    
@status varchar(20),  
@analyst varchar(max),    
@qualitycheck varchar(max) 
)as    

declare @value as varchar(20)    

INSERT INTO tbl_ProjectDetails(ProjectName,ProjectNos,Task_assigned,Startdate,enddate,Analyst,Qualitycheck,flag,Status_Name)VALUES (@projectname,@projectnos,@Task_assigned,@Startdate,@enddate,@analyst,@qualitycheck,0,@status)
```

Comment: You should make Startdate and enddate parameter of type datetime or datetime2 if corresponding values on table is datetime or datetime2

Comment: What is value for `@startdate` and `@enddate`? Since both parameter are type of `varchar` so probable reason for error is invalid casting from `string` to `datetime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am getting error

Top tip; always post the **exact error message**, and ideally sample input values that create that error; I strongly suspect that it is no coincidence that you're asking this question on 13th January; you might want to check that yesterday's data didn't record as the 1st of December (and Sunday the 1st of November, etc). However... moving on...

```
@Startdate varchar(30),    
@enddate varchar(30),
```

The fundamental trick here is: **don't do that**. And certainly don't just blindly cast those values by treating them "as is". The recommended approach is to parse the values *at the calling layer*, so those might become:

```
@Startdate datetime,
@enddate datetime,
```

(or similar; there are other date/time data types; it should match the table), and worry about the format in the calling code:

```
var start = DateTime.Parse[Exact](startText, ...); // some expected format/culture/etc
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Startdate", start);
```

(etc)